# Azure SQL Output

Tags: sql, azure

Consider the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT TOP 10
       dbo.LT_Bills.BillID,
       dbo.LT_Bills.BillNum,
       dbo.LT_Bills.SpanDesc,
       dbo.LT_Bills.BillType,
       dbo.LT_BillsHistory.HistoryDate,
       dbo.LT_BillsHistory.HistoryNum,
       dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics.TopicID
FROM (dbo.LT_Bills INNER JOIN dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics ON dbo.LT_Bills.BillID = dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics.BillID) INNER JOIN dbo.LT_BillsHistory ON dbo.LT_Bills.BillID = dbo.LT_BillsHistory.BillID
WHERE dbo.LT_Bills.Quatrain = 18 AND 
dbo.LT_BillsHistory.CreateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2018/05/01' AND '2018/05/12' 
dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics.TopicID IN dbo.MJ_Bills_GetTopicFamilyList
```

I'm having difficulties on running this query in Azure Data Studio using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 as my main DSN, it displays me the following error "Incorrect syntax near dbo" found in the last line of the WHERE clause declaration. Basically what i'm trying to do is to generate a report using a specific timestamp in order to make duplicate that we're writing or documented during that day. Can someone help me determine the main problem and provide me a viable solution for this problem? Thanks!!

Comment: You're missing `AND` from the last line.

Comment: Hi Mika! Thanks for the feedback. I already tried declaring AND at the beginning of the line code but it gives the same error.

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT TOP 10 B1.BillID, B1.BillNum ,B1.SpanDesc, B1.BillType,B2.HistoryDate, B2.HistoryNum, B1.TopicID
FROM ( dbo.LT_Bills INNER JOIN dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics ON dbo.LT_Bills.BillID = dbo.LT_Bills_2_Topics.BillID) AS B1 
INNER JOIN dbo.LT_BillsHistory AS B2 ON B1.BillID = B2.BillID
WHERE B1.Quatrain = 18 
AND B2.CreateTimeStamp BETWEEN '2018/05/01' AND '2018/05/12' 
AND B1.TopicID IN dbo.MJ_Bills_GetTopicFamilyList`. If still get the error, try to delete `AND B1.TopicID IN dbo.MJ_Bills_GetTopicFamilyList` to check if this cause the error.